# Cannot add an object with observers to a Realm

Tags: mongodb, swiftui, realm

I am new to SwiftUI and realm. I have created a Customer class as written below. I am trying to add some information to Realm database. My code is like this. And when I am trying to run it, I am getting error: "Cannot add an object with observers to a Realm."

Realm version is 10.28.6
SwiftUI 5
Xcode 13.4

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

class Customer: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {

    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var accountNumber = ""
    @Persisted var customerName = ""
    @Persisted var phoneNumber = ""
    @Persisted var address = ""
    @Persisted var city = ""
    @Persisted var state = ""
    @Persisted var zip = ""
}
```

---

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  ProjTests
//
// Realm 10.28.6

import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.realm) var realm
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

   @ObservedRealmObject var customer = Customer()
 //   @ObservedRealmObject var customer: Customer
    

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Customer Name")
                        TextField("Name", text: $customer.customerName)
                            .disableAutocorrection(true)
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    }
                }
                Section {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text("Phone Number")
                        TextField("10-digit Phone Number", text: $customer.phoneNumber)
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    }
                }
                Section {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Address")
                        TextField("Address", text: $customer.address)
                        TextField("City", text: $customer.city)
                        TextField("State", text: $customer.state)
                        TextField("PIN Code", text: $customer.zip)
                    }
                }

                Section {
                    DatePicker("Date", selection: $customer.loanDate, displayedComponents: .date)
                }

                HStack() {
                    Button("Submit") {

                        customer.accountNumber = generateAccountNumber()

                        try? realm.write {
                          realm.add(customer)
                          }
                        }

                    }
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 15, alignment: .center)
            }

        .navigationTitle("Add New Customer")
        }
    }
}


extension ContentView {
    func generateAccountNumber() -> String {
        let newAccountNumber = Int.random(in: 10000000..<99999999)
        return(String(newAccountNumber))
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I will be very thankful for your help.

Comment: The use case is a bit unclear but let me try this: Realm observers are used to watch for changes to objects that are already managed. e.g. Create some objects, write them and then add an observer to notify the app if those objects change. See the [Docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui-guide/#open-a-realm) but I believe the issue here is how the object is being defined `@ObservedRealmObject var customer = Customer()` should be `@ObservedRealmObject var allCustomers: Customers` to load an observe all customers. If observing is not needed then you don't need that call at all.